# How to show a placeholder image in nextjs image component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I am trying to show images from the API calls. I want to show a placeholder image in case there are no images or any errors. For that, I wrote this code,

```
const [errorImage, setErrorImage] = useState(null);

  <Image
                            src={`${imageUrl}/${item.image}`}
                            alt="image"
                            layout="fill"
                            objectFit="contain"
                            onError={(e) => {
                              if (!errorImage) {
                                setErrorImage(true);
                                e.target.src = "/static/placeholder.jpg";
                              }
                            }}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the state of `errorImage` when you set it to `true` will cause the components to re-render, so you don't need to set `e.target.src` directly.

**Option 1**
Instead, you can do the following:

```
const [errorImage, setErrorImage] = useState(null);
const errorImageUrl = "/static/placeholder.jpg";

  const url = errorImage ? errorImageUrl : `${imageUrl}/${item.image}`;
  <Image
    src={url}
    alt="image"
    layout="fill"
    objectFit="contain"
    onError={(e) => {
      if (!errorImage) {
        setErrorImage(true);
      }
    }}
```

**Option 2**
Alternatively, you can use the new `placeholder` prop that was added to `<Image>` component in NextJS 11. This will show a blurry version of the image you provide.

```
  <Image
    src={url}
    alt="image"
    layout="fill"
    placeholder="/static/placeholder.jpg"
    objectFit="contain"
```

Comment: After implementation of the above-mentioned solution, I am getting some weird behaviors like some of my components showing images and some of my components showing all of the images with placeholders though I am getting images from api.